# mysql order by from a different table breaks ranking

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that grabs tags for a list of articles and limits it to under 5 tags per article. This works pretty well.

Here's the query:

```
SET @rank=null, @val=null;
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT r.article_id, c.`category_name`, c.`category_id`, 
@rank := IF( @val = r.article_id, @rank +1, 1 ) AS rank, 
@val := r.article_id
FROM  `article_category_reference` r
INNER JOIN  `articles_categorys` c ON c.category_id = r.category_id
WHERE r.article_id
IN ( 1,2 )
ORDER BY r.`article_id` ASC
) AS a
WHERE rank < 5
```

However, I have specific tags I want to show up first which have a column of "show_first" 0/1 and I want them included first and be counted.

I've tried doing:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (c.`show_first` = 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, r.`article_id` ASC
```

Which breaks the rank counting, so all tags end up showing.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `article_category_reference` (
  `ref_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for table `article_category_reference`
--
ALTER TABLE `article_category_reference`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ref_id`),
  ADD KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  ADD KEY `article_id` (`article_id`);

CREATE TABLE `articles_categorys` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_name` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `quick_nav` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_genre` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `show_first` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

--
-- Indexes for table `articles_categorys`
--
ALTER TABLE `articles_categorys`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`);

-- And some data:

INSERT INTO `articles_categorys` (`category_id`, `category_name`, `quick_nav`, `is_genre`, `show_first`) VALUES
(1, 'one', 1, 0, 0),
(2, 'two', 1, 0, 0),
(3, 'three', 1, 0, 0),
(4, 'four', 0, 0, 0),
(5, 'five', 0, 0, 0),
(6, 'six', 0, 0, 0),
(7, 'seven', 0, 0, 1),
(8, 'eight', 0, 0, 1);

INSERT INTO `article_category_reference` (`ref_id`, `article_id`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 1, 3),
(4, 1, 4),
(5, 1, 5),
(6, 1, 6),
(7, 1, 7),
(8, 1, 8),
(9, 2, 1),
(10, 2, 2),
(11, 2, 3),
(12, 2, 4),
(13, 2, 5),
(14, 2, 6),
(15, 2, 7),
(16, 2, 8);
```

Fiddle of how it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1de99/1/0

Fiddle of it not working with me wanting some to always show first: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d36b7/1 (adding in a second group seems to break the ranking system)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Added tables + a fiddle to show the working version that doesn't deal with tags i want to show first. Still fiddling to show the non-working example where I want "show_first" to be included...

Comment: Added example data, added link to show how it breaks ranking system.

Comment: The `ORDER BY CASE...` is not what's breaking your query, it's the `r.article_id IN (1,2)` which is breaking the ranking system. Changing that to `r.article_id IN (1)` gives the desired output: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d36b7/4

Comment: @NaughtySquid Thank you for adding the sample schema and data. Has Nick solved this for you? (if he has, I wonder why he hasn't posted an answer) Maybe I haven't had enough coffee yet today, but it is not instantly clear what your issue is.  I expect it will become crystal clear if you post your desired resultset so that I can compare that against your incorrect resultset. (am I meant to be looking at the fiddle version `1`?)

Comment: No his comment doesn't solve it. The whole point is to pull more than one group, will see about a better fiddle.

Comment: The rank is used to count how many it pulls in per group. To limit each group to no more than 4.

Comment: I'm confused now, as running the second sqlfiddle in phpmyadmin works as expected, but doesn't on that site.

Comment: ...and I'll add that often complex queries can have a few different successful designs.  Just because you receive one working solution doesn't mean that there isn't another which might be better.  It is worth completing your question details so that you have the best chance of receiving the best possible solution.

Comment: @Strawberry is there a better way?

Comment: @mickmackusa it's hard to show, because i have an older working version that's different, but it doesn't work in sqlfiddle so it's impossible for me to show it properly. At least with the current answer, people have an idea and if people think they can improve - go ahead.

Comment: Okay, well, you seem satisfied with Sagar's answer, so I'll move along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not in the where condition, it's about the ranking that you are creating.

As you will see in my answer, I have created one inner query which will get that record in specific order and apply accurate ranking.

If you check your **inner query**, it's shows that all rows have the same rank and that is due to that ordering issue.

So I have added the `ORDER BY` clause in innermost query, and then filtered out records which have `rank1` less than `5`.

```
SET @rank1=null, @val=null;

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a.article_id, a.`category_name`, a.`category_id`, 
           @rank1 := IF( @val = a.article_id, @rank1 +1, 1 ) AS rank1, 
           @val := a.article_id
    FROM (
        SELECT r.article_id, c.`category_name`, c.`category_id`
        FROM  `article_category_reference` r
        INNER JOIN  `articles_categorys` c ON c.category_id = r.category_id
        GROUP BY r.article_id, c.`category_name`, c.`category_id`
        ORDER BY r.`article_id`,CASE WHEN (c.`show_first` = 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC
    ) AS a
) Z
WHERE Z.rank1 < 5;
```

You can check [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d36b7/40).

Comment: _Try This_ answer are low-value on StackOverflow because they do very little to educate the OP and thousands of potential researchers.  Every time you post an answer, always include how your solution works and why it is advisable.

Comment: Nope. Did you test it? Shows all of them, no limit placed as expected.

Comment: @mickmackusa You can check my answer. I am waiting for his answer that ,if it get resolve his problem or not.Once get confirmation then i can explain my logic to him.

Comment: While that works, you're now selecting all possible article id's, as my example shows I want to pick specific id's using IN.

Comment: Yes, that you can filter out.

Comment: As you have only TWO article id `1,2`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I added "WHERE r.article_id IN (1,2)" to the inner most subquery and it does indeed seem to work.

Could you please update your answer to explain why it works?

Comment: I would appreciate more text to explain exactly how it's working and why my original stuff did not :)

Comment: You can check my updated answer, may be it clears your doubt.

Comment: Well, it works perfectly as I want it to when I add in the IN to pick specific ID's and I haven't seen any other way to work it, so I have accepted your answer - thank you.